# Animate insertAdjacentHTML in JS

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to animate the insertAdjacentHTML in Jquery? Right now it just pastes it directly in the assigned div.

Current function

```
$(".select-category").click(function(){
  addSelect("<%= j render "userselections/select-companies", companies: @companies %>");
});

function addSelect(selectHTML) {
  var category_selection = document.getElementById('product-list');
  category_selection.innerHTML = "";
  category_selection.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', selectHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After inserting the html elements into dom tree, you must retrieve width or height of a related element to trigger DOM reflows.

```
function addSelect(selectHTML) {
  var category_selection = document.getElementById('product-list');
  category_selection.innerHTML = "";
  category_selection.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', selectHTML);
  // this code is for triggering DOM reflows
  category_selection.clientHeight;
  // Implement transitions here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lewis! Putting the DOM reflows and transition after the insertAdjecentHTML executes the insertion first right?

Comment: @Pimmesz Yes obviously. DOM reflow is basically for recalculating the sizes and positions of related elements. That's why it needs to be called after elements are inserted into dom tree.

Comment: Thanks! So the transition can be done upon the element? For example

category_selection.className = 'fadeIn';

Comment: @Pimmesz Yes, it can.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.fadeIn`, for example:

```js
const newDiv = $('<div>new text</div>')
  .css('display', 'none')
  .fadeIn(1000);
$('#container').append(newDiv);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>text</div>
</div>
```

Or any CSS transition you can think of

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For me the 'new div' is a partial being rendered in Rails. Im not too sure whether this would be possible for such a rendered partial as well? I've updated my code to include the full JS code to make it a bit more clear.